# PyQT LineEdit input validation, stop user from being able to backspace

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

Hi in an effort to learn, I have created this basic program to ping a host running on Windows.

Please critique and correct.

My biggest concern is with the disable_button function.

I have made sure that input in the "line_edit_hostname" is only valid if the user has entered a string with more the 1 character and has a "." in the text.

The reason I did this is because ping was crashing when I entered a string without a '.'.

However there was a way around it, once the user entered a string with more then one character and a '.', they could hit the backspace button and then proceed with the program.

I was going to put a while loop on the disable_button function, so it could keep an eye on the text validation, however this seemed to crash the program.

After reading I was under the impression it had to do with threading not being used on the function disable_button function. I attempted the standard threading module and did not make any progress, hence I found myself here asking for help :)

If someone could correct it with proper threading or perhaps even re-write a better version where I can learn that would be great.

Thanks for your time.

```
#!python3

import subprocess
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

# import threading

""" An example of a GUI Program that can ping a host """


# Class for the Application
class NetworkCheck(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)

        # make it a vertical box layout in the main form
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        # Widgets
        # When we add self in front of a Variable they become instance wide
        self.label_hostname = QLabel("Please enter a Hostname")
        self.line_edit_hostname = QLineEdit()
        self.label_ip = QLabel("Host IP Address:")
        self.line_edit_ip_address = QLineEdit()
        self.btn_ok = QPushButton("Ok")
        self.btn_clear = QPushButton("Clear")
        self.btn_exit = QPushButton("Exit")

        # Always add PlaceHolder Text before adding
        # The Widget to the layout
        self.line_edit_hostname.setPlaceholderText("example.com")
        self.line_edit_hostname.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        # calls the text_input function we defined to control the input of text to
        # make sure it has a "." so the program doesn't crash...
        self.line_edit_hostname.setText("")

        # When results show in the IP Address and Set it as a Read Only Field..
        self.line_edit_ip_address.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.line_edit_ip_address.setReadOnly(True)

        # Align the Labels in the Center of the Window'
        self.label_hostname.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.label_ip.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)

        # Now we need to add the above Widgets to the Form
        layout.addWidget(self.label_hostname)
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit_hostname)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_ip)
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit_ip_address)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn_ok)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn_clear)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn_exit)

        # Now we need to Save the Layout
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # Change the Main Window Title Name
        self.setWindowTitle("Check Host")

        # Removes the Focus from QLineEdit()
        # This means that the text will always display
        # in the QLineEdit field
        self.setFocus()

        # Stop the Window from being Stretched
        # Sets the Width to 250 by 200 Height
        self.setFixedSize(250, 200)

        # Exit button to close the Main window
        self.btn_exit.clicked.connect(self.close)

        # Clear Button will clear the line edit fields and disable the Ok button
        self.btn_clear.clicked.connect(self.clear_fields)

        # Ok button to perform the function...
        # disables the button by default..
        self.btn_ok.setEnabled(False)
        # if Text is entered in the hostname field it calls the disable_button function
        # and a "." is also entered in the line_edit field..
        self.line_edit_hostname.textChanged.connect(self.disable_button)

    def clear_fields(self):
        """Clear the Line Edit Boxes.. and Disables the Ok push button"""
        self.line_edit_hostname.setText("")
        self.line_edit_ip_address.setText("")
        self.btn_ok.setEnabled(False)

    def get_ip(self):
        try:

            # defines the hostname variable to use in the command
            hostName = self.line_edit_hostname.displayText()

            ping = subprocess.Popen(
                ["ping", "-n", "1", hostName],
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.PIPE
            )

            # output of the above command
            ping_output, error = ping.communicate()

            # get rid of the bytes output...
            ping_output = ping_output.decode("utf-8")

            # Clean the output to get the IP only...
            ip_start = ping_output.index("[") + 1
            ip_end = ping_output.index("]")

            # get only the ip address..
            # global ip_output
            ip_output = ping_output[ip_start:ip_end]

            # displays the ip address in the line_editip_address field.
            self.line_edit_ip_address.setText(ip_output)

        except Exception:
            # Dialog Box: adds the Title and the Massage...
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Warning", "The Ping Lookup Failed...")
            # Terminates the Application...
            sys.exit()
            # return

    # enables the button get results once text has been entered in the line edit field hostname
    # and a "." is also entered in the line_edit field..
    def disable_button(self):
        # while True:
        if len(self.line_edit_hostname.text()) > 0 and "." in str(self.line_edit_hostname.text()):
            # if the text is greater then 1 char it enables the button
            self.btn_ok.setDisabled(False)
            # connect to the "OK" button we crated the in the UI and calls the get_ip function
            self.btn_ok.clicked.connect(self.get_ip)
            # break


# Calling the Application Class
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = NetworkCheck()
    # enable threading on the get_ip function from the Window class that holds the application.
    # t1 = threading.Thread(target=window.get_ip)
    # t1.start()
    # t1.join()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `Enter` to proceed with the program??

Comment: Nothing? Where did I say there is a problem using enter?